# How to Use threads efficiently in Image Processing?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

Objective : To Develop an algorithm for finding the Circles in given image

Implementation Part : VC++ 2010 + Using opencv library to find the Circles

Inputs : ROI (X,y,Width,Height) , IplImage* (Input_Image)
Algorithm : So here calling the Opencv Circle function in the given ROI

So For ex:

if i have 20 circles in image, i will be having 20 ROI's

Problem: So every time algorithm is acting on sequence basis

**Input -> ROI Function -> Find Cirlce in given ROI -> return Circle Parameter -> Output**

TO DO: Need to reduce the processing time using Multithreading

Can I use two threads to do this in parallel  ???

Comment: Using Only threading concept not OpenMP please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, if you make sure to handle the return properly. One way to do so would be to use OpenMP possibly.

```
std::vector<ResultType> result;
#pragma omp parallel for shared(image_data) //using openMP
for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
  result.push_back(CircleRoutine(image_data, ROI[i]));
}
```

That should give you an idea what you can do for parallezing the task.

Note: if your final result is dependent on the order of finding the circles, then you have to do it sequentially. If it doesn't matter, that would be a perfect routine to make it parallel.

Note2: I don't know the implementation, but OpenCV might thread the circle finding already, resulting in no speed up by threading it.